# Strange behavior of transform function in Pandas when using x.unique()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

Given the following Data Frame:

```
tdf1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['r1', 'r1', 'r1', 'r2', 'r2', 'r2', 'r3'],
                   'B' :  ['t1', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't4', 't5']})
>>> tdf1
    A   B
0  r1  t1
1  r1  t1
2  r1  t2
3  r2  t3
4  r2  t4
5  r2  t4
6  r3  t5
```

I want to group the data by column A and create a column C that contains all elements form each group. So the resulting Data Frame should look like this:

```
>>> res
   A   B   C
0  r1  t1  t1t2
1  r1  t1  t1t2
2  r1  t2  t1t2
3  r2  t3  t3t4
4  r2  t4  t3t4
5  r2  t4  t3t4
6  r3  t5  t5
```

I hoped that the following would do most of the work required:

```
tdf1.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x:  x.unique())
```

But instead of getting a set of unique values for each group I just get repeated column B. It looks like a x.unique() is applied to each cell instead of all cells in the group.

However, if the column B has numbers and instead of using x.unique() I use  x.sum() the results are as expected all cells in each group contain sum of the group.

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: Are you looking for a string like `'t1t2'` (without spaces) in the `C` column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is a bug , `transform` converts the result it gets to the same size of the group, hence when you send it a list of unique elements, it repeats the list so that it becomes the same size of the group , hence for the first group, you get `['t1','t2','t1']` , and then each element is applied at each index.

If you want a string like `'t1t2'` , in the resulting column, you should use `str.join` to join the result and provide that to `transform`. Example -

```
tdf1['C'] = tdf1.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()))
```

Demo -

```
In [9]: tdf1
Out[9]:
    A   B
0  r1  t1
1  r1  t1
2  r1  t2
3  r2  t3
4  r2  t4
5  r2  t4
6  r3  t5

In [10]: tdf1.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()))
Out[10]:
0    t1t2
1    t1t2
2    t1t2
3    t3t4
4    t3t4
5    t3t4
6      t5
Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

If you want elements column `'C'` to be a list of unique elements of the group, then you would need to pass `x.unique()` inside another list. Example -

```
tdf1['C'] = tdf1.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: [x.unique()])
```

Demo -

```
In [11]: tdf1.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: [x.unique()])
Out[11]:
0    [t1, t2]
1    [t1, t2]
2    [t1, t2]
3    [t3, t4]
4    [t3, t4]
5    [t3, t4]
6        [t5]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the explantaion. It makes sense now.